# What is humorous about calling people "mortals"?

Tags: meaning

The following definition of *mortal* is from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mortal):

> [humorous] a person contrasted with others regarded as being of higher status or ability

It gives this sentence as an example:

> *an ambassador had to live in a style which was not expected of* ***lesser mortals***

Where is the humorous point of it? I can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sense is a play on the contrast between **mortals** and immortals (specifically, the gods). By calling ordinary people **mortals** and contrasting them to someone else (such as ambassadors), the speaker is implying that the "immortals" think they're like the gods.

Comment: Well, actually, in OP's specific context the ambassador *is* classified as a "mortal" (but not a *lesser* one, so by implication he's a *greater mortal*). Your interpretation would be correct if the reference had been to ***mere** mortals*, but it's close enough.

Comment: The use of the word *lesser* in this case is merely an understated shading of the comparison; the humor derives from the implication that even the tacitly *greater mortals* aren't really quite mortal.

Answer (score 1):

We are *all* mortals, are we not? So, using a phrase like *lesser mortals* suggests some sort of hierarchy that doesn't really exist. It's not the kind of humor that would make you LOL, but it might bring an amused smile.

Here's another example:

> *LeBron James does things on the basketball court that mortals should not be able do.*

That wording elevates James to an above-human status. It's a somehat "humorous" way of saying his talents are seemingly superhuman.