# Is lesser mortals a right word?

Tags: word-usage

Can we use the word "lesser mortals" in an official usage? I am really concerned whether this word is a slang or an appropriate word.

Comment: That's actually two words.  The term does usually convey a little bit of tongue-in-cheek humor, but can you tell us what you mean by "official usage"?

Comment: Appropriate where?  Are you asking if the term "lesser mortals" is acceptable in formal English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is used in a humorous way or probably in a taunting way.

> "Do you see the way he treats us after becoming the CEO of the company?" 
>   "Of course, he's now the boss buddy! For him, we are like *lesser mortals!"*

This means that he treats them as people with no significance, importance, value, capability etc..

> All season they have managed to compete with just 3 players with us lesser mortals playing up to help out -[YourDictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/mortal).

[Related answer here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/what-is-humorous-about-calling-people-mortals)

Answer (score 1):

When you use *lesser mortals* to designate actual people (as it is usually done), you do insinuate that someone else behaves as if they are divine.

Although this is fine when meant jokingly or sarcastically among friends or colleagues, I would certainly be wary of using it in any official communication, since not everybody might be very pleased when they are told they behave like a god - it insinuates arrogance, for one thing.

So, depending on what you mean with "official usage", I would probably say "no, do not use it".

In general, a very good rule, also in this case, is "when in doubt, don't".

If you are not sure if you can use a certain word, idiom or expression in the mail, letter or speech that you are preparing, simply *do not use it*. Be on the safe side and use something you are sure about. Your *lesser mortals* may refer to the people on the work floor, to "the other players in the team", to "the students".

Simply describing what you mean without using any idiomatic jokes or references may tend to make your text a bit boring, *but* you avoid the risk of insulting people with an inappropriate joke.

Answer (score 0):

In the term "lesser mortals", it means others are lesser than someone superior in knowledge, capability etc. even though each one of us is mortal and will die. (It does not mean others are less likely to die and we are more mortal.) Deriding anyone by assuming an air of superiority should be avoided in official communication as people have to work as a team in offices. So this term should not be used in official communication like emails or blogs. It can be used in blogs if referring to someone who is an outsider like rival companies who are not doing so well. For example, "For lesser mortals it remains a dream to match our year on year profits".

Answer (score 0):

Referring to others as "lesser mortals" would be seen as extremely rude, arrogant, and prone to instant punishment by the "lesser mortals".

Referring to yourself and your group as "lesser mortals" is usually meant in a sarcastic way, to set the group apart from someone who thinks they are better than the rest, but clearly isn't.

In an official document, it is unlikely that you would be able to use the word without upsetting someone.